How can I put a bullet point above or below the current line and have the same indent level automatically?
Let's say I have these bullet points
- First Line
- Second Line
    - Third Line

On the second line I do dd, move down to the third line and do p, the second line gets pasted below with no indent, when I want it to automatically have one indent like the third line. Nothing happens after I do :set autoindent :set smartindent or vice versa for both.

You want to do ]p to paste with indentation. There's a duplicate somewhere...

Yep ]p works thanks!
